# Set null in Rails when radio button not checked

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 4. In record id `100`, the `gender` is set as `male` because it was set previously with radio buttons `male` and `female`. When editing the record again, I could use Javascript to clear the radio buttons, so the params for the `gender` will not be sent.

Now when I save the form again, the `gender` remains as `male` even no `params[:post][:gender]` is sent. I understand this is normal, but how do I set `post.gender` as `null` when no such params is sent?

Set as `null` when no param is sent. I don't wanna use hidden field because it's messy.

Comment: you could use server side `unless params[:post][:gender].present? post.gender = nil end`

Comment: is your field in DB boolean?

Comment: @PopescuAlexandruConstantin There are other fields too. I don't wanna specify one by one.

Comment: @OlegSobchuk Some boolean, some string.

Comment: you don't have to, you can update all your attributes once and then set the gender, of course you have to save it `post.save`